# how to store login infos Android kotlin with jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I am developing an application where I have multiple screens with compose.
I am using navigation-compose.
What should I do with the log in infos? (username, JWT token)
Should i save it somewhere? If yes, how?

I tried to pass the object to the navigation, but it accepts only NavTypes.
I also tried to have a shared viewmodel but this option seems like a workaround or is it the right way to do it?

Comment: There are many ways to do it, so this ends up being an opinionated matter. I personally would store the credentials in the repository layer and retrieve it from there on the view-model.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to avoid passing unnecessary data via navigation.

You can store the username / auth token in SharedPreferences using [Jetpack DataStore](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore) and write to it when logging in, then read from it wherever else you need after you have logged in. If you are not using Coroutines yet you can just use a standard SharedPreferences manager as provided by the Android framework, as Jetpack DataStore is coroutine based.